# Markdown behavior next to ellipsis in chat is different from the site

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

On the site, an ellipsis character `…` (U+2026) is considered "not a word" and allows use of formatting right next to it. To illustrate what I mean:

1. Formatting enabled: *foo*
2. Formatting disabled within a word: *foo*bar
3. Formatting enabled next to ellipsis: *foo*…
4. Formatting enabled next to three periods: *foo*...

In chat, the third case behaves differently. It appears as `*foo*…` in chat, similar to the second case, instead of formatting the term.

FWIW the Markdown preview on the site gets it right.

Since `…` is just <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> on English Mac OS X keyboard layouts, it can easily be used.